# create json array from php fetch mysqli_fetch_stmt

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to create a json array in my php mysql script to return to my application. My vendor does not have mysqlnd installed so I am forced to use bind result... below is code that gets my data correctly but I not sure how to fix the data to match  the json array id need.

Here is the php code:

```
  $cnt = "";
    $empty=array();
$resultArray=array();
$row=array();

    $sql =
    "select
    value as column1,
    value2 as column2
            from setting where name = ?";

    error_log("\n sql: " . $sql ,3,"master.log");

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql))
    {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $sqlvalue1);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $cnt = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

            error_log("\n cnt=? : " . $cnt ,3,"master.log");

            if ($cnt == 0)
            {
                    error_log("\n cnt=0 : " . $cnt ,3,"master.log");
                    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$empty));
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                    exit;
            }
            if ($cnt > 0)
            {
                    error_log("\n cnt>0 : " . $cnt ,3,"master.log");
                    $resultArray = array();
                    $tempArray = array();
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $column1, $column2);

                    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                    {
                            error_log("\n while_json 2: " . $column1 . " " . $column2 ,3,"master.log");
                            //$tempArray = $row;
                            //array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
                    }
                    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$resultArray));
                    error_log("\n while_json 3: " . print_R($resultArray,TRUE) ,3,"master.log");
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                    exit;
            }
    }
    else
    {
            $resultArray = array(array("success" => "NO", "message" => mysqli_errno($conn) . " " . mysqli_error($conn) , "count" => 0));
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>$resultArray));
            exit;
    }
```

The json data should look like: (2 Rows returned)

{"result":[{"column1":"0","column2":"VB0023220131"},{"column1":"5","column2":"CE004342420131"}]}

So how do I (in the while loop) create the string above.

thanks. PS the may be multiple row so the

Comment: This sort of code is *considerably* less verbose if you use the `mysqli` object-oriented interface. `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, ...)` becomes `$stmt->bind_result(...)` and so on. I'd strongly encourage you to use this approach. The procedural method dates from the PHP 4 era and isn't really a good idea to use today.

Comment: I have the same code in ooi format but again have the same issue the vendor does not have mysqlnd so I need to use bind fetch which returns the data in ooi but still need to know how to create the format

Comment: What I'm saying is there's a lot of code in this question that confuses what you're actually trying to do. For example, you close the connection to MySQL arbitrarily. You force-exit from the script. A lot of this could be cleaned up and then mistakes become more obvious.